# Android Date Format: Alternative to "O" from C#

Tags: android, date, string-formatting

I need to get the following date format: `2015-04-24T10:32:49.2573151Z`

In C# I have the following, which gives me the above:

```
string timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("O");
```

I need to have the same format in android. I have done the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
s.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
String timestamp = s.format(new Date());
```

While it gives me what I need, I feel like it's a bit hackish, because I added the T and Z as a literal. Is it correct to do it like that, or is there a standard format pattern that can give me that string?

Comment: there is no standard format pattern, in Android You have to do it like You did...it´s correct...